# Nginx reverse proxy - Ask for basic auth credentials and pass them on to the target API

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, basic-authentication

I wrote a REST API in Haskell delivering HTML to be viewed in a browser and am currently trying to host it using Nginx's reverse proxy.
My backend however requires Basic Auth credentials, which the Nginx server doesn't provide.

How can I configure the reverse proxy, so that it asks for credentials when a GET request is made via the browser, but doesn't validate them and passes them on to the backend?
I have tried about half a dozen suggestions on stackoverflow, reddit etc. but haven't found a working solution.

This is my current config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;

        auth_basic "user-realm";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_header Accept;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        #proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_set_header ns_server-ui yes;
    }
}
```

A few of the articles I tried or read are the following:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/couchbase/comments/2wksmj/authorization_headers_when_using_nginx_as_a/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/511206/nginx-forward-http-auth-user
- https://serverfault.com/questions/230749/how-to-use-nginx-to-proxy-to-a-host-requiring-authentication

All or most seem to focus on how to let Nginx take over the authorization, however I want it to only pass on the credentials entered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of trying I found out that my config isn't even used since for some reason it always matches with the default config.

I didn't figure out how to solve this, but I got the proxy to work as I intended it when I changed this

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

to this

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
```

Nginx then automatically asks for the credentials and passes them on to the backend.
(So in the end my config simply wasn't being used and therefore nothing rerouted to the backend)

Hopefully this saves someone some searching time in the future :)